# Array Tree...Maybe recursion?

Tags: arrays, recursion, theory

I am trying to divide arrays recursively... I think that is what this would be called haha....

For instance, lets say the initial array contains 50 values the highest being 97 and the lowest being 7... I want to split this array into two, dividing them based on whether they are greater or lower than the midrange of the entire set. The midrange being 52...( (97+7)/2 )
Then I want to divide these two arrays using the same method and so on, ideally having a program that repeat this process an arbitrary number of times....

```
Load Values into array1
Find Midrange 
For every value in array1{
       if value > midrange{
           assign value to ArrayHigh1}
       Else{ assign value to ArrayLow1}
}
Perform same thing on ArrayHigh1 and ArrayHigh2
```

Etc etc etc.

I'm having trouble figuring out how I would create the successive arrays (ArrayHigh2 3 4 etc)

Also, I feel like there must be an easier way to do this, but I cannot think of one at the moment...

Thanks for the help

Comment: So is this a question on how to do a Quicksort implementation? Also, do you have a particular language for implementation in mind? Creating arrays will be done differently for different languages.

Comment: Uh, I didn't realize that it was called quicksort, but after reading about it, it seems very similar... And I was hoping to use this in Processing for an art project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be working your way towards a [B-tree](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/B-tree) or an implementation of [Merge-](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Merge_sort) or [Quicksort.](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Quicksort) Plenty of [reference implementations](http://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/~jmor159/PLDS210/qsort.html) are [available online.](http://math.hws.edu/eck/cs225/s03/binary_trees/)

Though speaking generally, you might benefit greatly from reading [a book many here are familiar with.](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0262032937)

Comment: Alright, these sound like good places to start... Thanks for the help. I didn't realize this would require so much other research haha, but I suppose I'll be better off thoroughly understanding the topics.